# Download multiple files from ftp server with bash script

Tags: bash, backup, ftp

I have 2 or 3 FTP Servers where our hoster puts database backups each day. Since he only keeps one, I was orded to write a bash script for downloading alle database backups every day so we have more than the one day old backup.

I tried to get it working with ftp command, but since it seems I can't download an complete directory I thought I could do it with a for loop but that won't work with the ftp command and I always get an unxpected end of file error.

I should say,  only can connect via ftp on the server. No SSH access or something else!

At the moment I have this:

```
echo "Download all the database backups from honds ftp-servers"

SERVERS="ftp.srv1.de ftp.srv2.de"

#for SERVER in $SERVERS; do
    ftp -in ftp://user:pw@ftp.srv1.de << EOF
    binary
    get Datenbankbackup
EOF
```

Comment: Well would be a good Idea, but I don't have access via ssh to the ftp server. I can only connect via the ftp command or any other ftp client. And via the ftp command I can't tar the files.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forget that. I edited that already.

Comment: You’re trying to solve the wrong problem. Instead of trying to get the most basic FTP client to do your stuff, [use a proper client](http://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cd into the directory then use `mget` command to get all files in that directory:

```
ftp -in ftp://user:pw@ftp.srv1.de << EOF
    binary
    cd Datenbankbackup
    mget *
EOF
```

Comment: Well, that was pretty obviously, why didn't I thought about that... thanks, does what it should